# How to insert Russian ruble sign in vim (digraph)?

Tags: vim

Does Vim have Russian ruble sign? I want to insert it using digraph, eg: `i_^K_RB_<Ecs>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters

> Digraphs work by pressing CTRL-K and a two-letter combination while in insert mode. For example, in insert mode type:

And looking at the combinations in http://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html is looks like the two-letter combination you need is `=R`.

Hence in insert mode, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then press `=R` (`i_^K_=R_<Esc>`).
You should then see the ruble sign.

Comment: That's is right, but instead of ruble sign I get just `P`(using `=R`), `=P` gives Russian `П` letter. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the combination in the _correct order_? You might be typing `=` second ... you should type `=` _first_.

When I try this ....
`R=` combination gives Russian letter `Р`,
`P=` combination gives Russian letter `П `,
both `=R` and `=P` give Ruble letter `₽`.

Comment: Unfortunately, but vim gives either Р or П in whatever order I type: `=R / R= / =P / P=`. Hm...what is the reason?

Comment: Not sure, it might be related to your version of vim, font settings or certain locale settings. 
It's worth checking to see if your vim supports the digraphs feature (typing `:digraphs` should not give an error). You should also check that your vim was compiled with the multibytes feature: `vim --version | grep "multi_byte"` should have `+multi_byte not `-multi_byte`. If you need help getting digraphs to work, I would recommend opening another stack overflow question so that more people can help you.

Comment: Output of `vim --version | grep ..` is `+multi_byte     +terminfo`. `:digraphs` works ok and there is no problem with other symbols, only with ruble sign) I don't think the problem with font as well, because typing the sign literally using `^V` works properly. Anyway thank you for suggestions) I think I need to create separate issue like you advised.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit longer solution: `i^Vu20bd`. It means go insert mode, start typing non-digit literally (`^V`), then indicate 2-byte long **u**nicode value by `u` and finally enter hexadecimal `20bd` which is Russian ruble sign. The more information here `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`.